# how to change all pixels in a given rectangle

Tags: python, pixel

I need to create a function that takes in the dimensions of the rectangle and then the desired pixel color. So far, my function looks like this:

```
def makeRectangle(width, height, desiredPixel):

    # Begin with a rectangle image with all black pixels
    resultImage = EmptyImage(width, height)

    # Creates the total size of the rectangle image
    size = width * height

    # Change the color of all pixels
    for i in range(width):
        resultImage.setPILPixel(i, width, desiredPixel)

    return resultImage
```

I think that I need to be using a nested for loop but I can't find a way to get all pixel colors to change. The function I have now produces the middle line of pixels to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIL has a function to draw rectangles:

```
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(resultImage)
draw.rectangle([0,0,width,height], fill=desiredPixel)
```

Looping in Python is slow so it is best to find an optimized function to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear if you are trying to figure out how to loop, or just want to create a new image with a particular color. If the latter, you can specify the background color when you make a new image, so no need for the loop at all:

```
im = Image.new("RGB", (width, height), "white")
```

or you can specify the color using `fill` or just a hex value:

```
im = Image.new("RGB", (width,height), "#ddd" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate through both x and y dimensions to change all pixels:

```
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        resultImage.setPILPixel(x, y, desiredPixel)
```

should do the trick.